# Rails file field doesn't change the name when using multiple

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, nested-form-for

When using multiple for my file field, it displays a name with an array `[]` appending at the end, but I'm trying to get rid of it. I'm not getting the correct name as I'm supposed to. I'm supposed to remove the `[]` from the name by hard coding it, the name still gives me `business_photos[bizurl][]`.

```
<%= form_for BusinessPhoto.new, :html => {:class => "biz_image"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :bizurl, multiple: true, name: "business_photos[bizurl]" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :business_id, :value => @biz.id %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

With file_field it will automatically add the `[]` array in the name.

If you want to remove it you can use `file_field_tag` instead of `f.file_field`

```
f.file_field :foo, multiple: true, name: 'foo' # results in "name='foo[]'" (f is a form-helper)
file_field_tag :foo, multiple: true, name: 'foo' # results in "name='foo'"
```

Similar [discussion here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9830)

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing html option

```
:multipart => true
```

with form_for

Comment: i've had that before, but i still have `[]` at the end of the name

Comment: yeah I have restarted the server

Comment: From the [3.2 API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/) seems that the multipart is already set from the file_field method `self.multipart = true`